# hi i have question here is pseudo code about sift up and sift down on heaps

Tags: algorithm

i have following pseudo code :

```
void siftup(int n)
 pre condition n>0  && heap(1,n-1)
post heap(1,n)
 i=n;
 loop
/* invariant: heap(1,n)   except  perhaps 
  between    i and   its parent 
 if (i==1)
   break;
 p=i/2;
 if (x[p]<=x[i])
   break;
 swap(p,i);
i=p;
```

please help me to write it in real code i have question about loop  for example where is starting point of loop?

i have doen this and is  it correct?
public class siftup
{

public  static void main(String[]args)
{

int p;

int n=12;
int a[]=new int[]{15,20,12,29,23,17,22,35,40,26,51,19};

int i=n-1;
 while (i!=0)
{

if (i==1)
 break;

p=i/2;
 if (a[p]<=a[i]){
 int t=a[p];
a[p]=a[i];
a[i]=t;
}
i=p;

}

for (int j=0;j

}
}
//result is this
15
20
19
29
23
12
22
35
40
26
51
17

Comment: Please write your pseudo code with line brakes and inside a 'code' tags because this is unreadeble.

Comment: if you want real code you will need to pick a real language

Comment: possible duplicate of [question about siftdown operation on heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896811/question-about-siftdown-operation-on-heap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `h` is your heap and is a max-heap, its indexed from 0, and `n` is the number of elements, then this should work:

```
int position = n - 1;
while (position > 0 && h[(position - 1) / 2] <= h[position]) // while the parent of the current node is smaller than the current child, swap it with its child (only in case of a max-heap, it's the other way around for a min-heap)
{
    swap(h[(position - 1) / 2] = h[position]);
    poistion = (position - 1) / 2;
}
```

> i have question about loop for example where is starting point of loop?

The loop starts with the last element of the heap array, as that is usually the one you want to move to the right position.